# Make the imageview to stretch to fit the screen on Android

Tags: android

**Hi**

Is there a working way to achieve this:

[image: Example]

...instead of this:

[image: Example2]

(little margin between the image and screen border)

I have used these codes but they didn't work:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

myImg.setMinimumWidth(width);
myImg.setMinimumHeight(height);

myImg.setMaxWidth(width);
myImg.setMaxHeight(height);
```

and this:

```
myImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: remove margin from your parent layout ............

Comment: can you post the xml code where you have implemented this layout?

Answer (score 3):

I'm presuming you are using a standard activity.

Is it possible that you have a relativelayout or linearlayout with padding as your viewgroup?

Comment: I was had padding "16" on my layout

Answer (score 1):

You  can use scaletype fitxy in xml that will resolve that issue.